# IE: return to a scrolled page with dynamic content via ajax

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer

I have a page that loads dynamic content via ajax. When I scroll down and follow a link and I return to my result page with the back button, Firefox remember the scrolled position (and doesn't launch the ajax query) but IE doesn't remember the page position and fires the ajax call.

Is there a way that IE remember the position inside the result page?

You can see the behaviour: http://www.todocoleccion.net/ventas/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we could solve the problem with a cookie with the last id of the item visited and when comming back, check this id and scroll to it.